# Why didn't Ichigo use Hollowfication after his fight with Aizen?

Tags: bleach

After his fight with Aizen, Ichigo lost all his Shinigami powers, but he did not lose his hollow powers right?
So why did he not use hollowfication in the fights that followed? Like vs ginjo, and the 'book of the end' guy

Answer (score 1):

Well, Ichigo didn't necessarily lose his Shinigami powers it was his spiritual pressure or powers, as stated in the chapter black * cough cough* I mean fullbring arc where he had some spiritual pressure left. Another reason that he didn't use hollowfcation is because white Ichigo and Zangetsu put all their power into Ichigo so he had the full power of hollowfcation just without the mask.

Comment: Hi @user63170, welcome to Anime & Manga SE. This answer could be improved by mentioning exactly what was stated in the Fullbring Arc. You can [edit] your post to add clarifications. Also, do take our [tour]!